# Tkinter treeview text not visible until client restart

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I have a program written in python 3.5 which scans a directory and stores the info in a SQLITE3 db. This info can be displayed in a ttk.treeview in the client.

The 2 main functions are 1) "scan" which adds the information to the db and 2) viewFiles which is below (it just grabs data from the db and displays it in the treeview).

During the scan function, a second tkinter window is opened and displays information on whats been scanned. If I try to use the viewFiles fucntion without a restart, the data displayed is invisible but I know the data is there because I can copy paste it into a text document). If I restart the client, the text is displayed correctly after pressing the button linked to the viewFiles function.

I think it must be something to do with the the focus shift thanks to this 2nd window opening during the scan process but I'm not sure and can't find any similar case to learn from.

```
def viewFiles(self):

    global dataTreeView   
    results = []

    foldersContentsToView = yieldFoldersToView()

    for dpath in foldersContentsToView:

            sqlstring= "SELECT * FROM DBDATA WHERE directorypath=:dpath"
            values = {"dpath": dpath}

            [results.append(i) for i in databaseFunctions.getDBobject().returnSelectQueryResults(sqlstring, values)]

    for e in results:
        dataTreeView.insert('', 'end', values=list(e))
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The answer depends on why the tree view is not visible.  Has it been placed or gridded properly?  Is so, perhaps you need focus_get() or lift().  http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html

Comment: It has been packed correctly. When the viewFiles is executed, the scroll bars activate and you can scroll up and down the set of value and even select rows. The only thing is you can't actually see the text. Unless you restart the client.   I tried using focus_get(), lift() even focus_force() on the treeview but no change...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the columns were being set up in the moment the treeview was ***created*** by querying the fields in the database. However before the first scan, there were no records in the db and so the columns were not being configured properly until a restart, after which data existed and could be queried on treeview creation.

To fix the issue, I moved the column configure data to the viewFiles function like so:

```
def viewFiles(self):

    global dataTreeView   

    audioDataTree['columns'] = returnListTableFields()

        #Configure Columns
        for column in listofdbtablefields():
            dataTree.column(column,width=len(column)*10)
            dataTree.heading(column, text=column)
            dataTree.column(column, anchor='center')

        #Hide First Column (TreeLabel)
        dataTree.column('#0',width=0) 

    results = []

    foldersContentsToView = yieldFoldersToView()

    for dpath in foldersContentsToView:

            sqlstring= "SELECT * FROM DBDATA WHERE directorypath=:dpath"
            values = {"dpath": dpath}

            [results.append(i) for i in databaseFunctions.getDBobject().returnSelectQueryResults(sqlstring, values)]

    for e in results:
        dataTreeView.insert('', 'end', values=list(e))
```